# why connection.timezone is None for postgres db connection in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-connection

I am exploring django with postgres. I have encountered a strange thing. `TIMEZONE` setting for my postgres connection(I am not talking about `TIME_ZONE` in settings.py) is surprisingly set to None. I have set timezone to `'Asia/Kolkata'` and `USE_TZ` is also True. As per django docs, when `USE_TZ` is True, the connection timezone `'UTC'` by default, while it'll be equal to the value of `TIME_ZONE` in settings.py, when `USE_TZ` is False. But, for me in both the cases, the value of connection.timezone is empty.

I have tried with sqlite3 backend, where I am getting expected results. I don't know, why I am not getting expected behaviour with postgres.

I am using django==1.10.5 and postgres is 9.5 on 64 bit machine. I am using following command to get connection's timezone.

```
from django.db import connection
print (connection.timezone)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`django.db.connection` is a common abstraction that wraps the database-specific connection.

You can access [the underlying database connection](https://github.com/django/django/blob/feb683c4c2c5ecfb61e4cb490c3e357450c0c0e8/django/db/backends/base/base.py#L49) with `connection.connection`.

In the case of PostgreSQL that will be a psycopg2 connection. The [documented](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.get_parameter_status) way to get the connection timezone with psycopg2 is `get_parameter_status("TimeZone")`.

Putting it all together, this should work:

```
connection.connection.get_parameter_status("TimeZone")
```

But wait! Database connections are created lazily, so that will only work if you've already performed some kind of database operation. To be sure you have a connection you can call `connection.ensure_connection()`, or, if you want a single expression:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.cursor().connection.get_parameter_status("TimeZone")
'UTC'
```

For reference, see the [`ensure_timezone()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/feb683c4c2c5ecfb61e4cb490c3e357450c0c0e8/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py#L187) method of the PostgreSQL database wrapper.